# How I can show tooltip in my situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the situation that you can see on the picture.

`overflow:hidden` in slider's container cut my tooltip.

What is the right way to show tooltips for me?

Tnx for help!

UPD:
slider's code start here https://github.com/aseredenko/Aligator/blob/master/index.html#L64

tooltips css start here https://github.com/aseredenko/Aligator/blob/master/css/main.css#L497
js here https://github.com/aseredenko/Aligator/blob/master/js/main.js#L94

[image]

Comment: It's bad practice to post a question on Stack Overflow with no code... If I can see your HTML/CSS I may be able to help you out.

Comment: @Rorschach120, OK. 1 minute

Comment: @Rorschach120, I'va added code example.

Comment: Since the tooltip isn't contained by the image, why not have it as part of 'item' instead of the image? That way you can still keep the image `overflow:hidden`. All you would have to do is move the tooltip outside of the image in the HTML and then change your jQuery selector. EDIT: And of course make some tweaks to the CSS, but I have no doubt you are capable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution of my problem. I am showing tooltip at the left of the block in fourth and fifth block.